# Win32Shutdown Method of the Win32_OperatingSystem Class

Tags: winapi

Does anyone can describe me the difference between
"Forced Shutdown" and "Forced Power Off" ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Shutdown" asks for a Windows shutdown *without* turning off the power.

Additional docs are available with the MSDN Library article for [ExitWindowsEx()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376868%28VS.85%29.aspx).  Note how the flag values are a one-to-one mapping with the WMI method flags.  Not an accident.

Comment: Power off - "Shuts down the system and turns off the power."
vs
Shutdown - "Shuts down the system to a point at which it is safe to turn off the power."

Anyway things seems to be the same :)
I tryed both ones and after the PC seems to be turned off in the both cases

Comment: Well, that's not normal.  Maybe your BIOS is overriding it.